# Get loop index of outer loop and end with comma

Tags: json, jinja2

In jinja2, I have a loop inside another loop and I want to write a comma if not last loop.

This is what I have so far:

```
// ksp = "{'a': ['someString', ['someString'], ['a1', 'a2']], 'b': ['someString', ['someString'], ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']]}"

"users": {
    {% for kvd in ksp %}
        {% set outer_loop = loop %}
        {% for kvt in ksp[kvd][2] %}
              "{{ kvt }}": {
                "username": "{{ ksp[kvd][1][0] }}"
         }{% if not outer_loop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}{{ '' }}{% endfor %}
},
```

This is what I'm getting:

```
"users": {
    "a1": {
        "username": "someString"
    },
    "a2": {
        "username": "someString"
    },
    "b1": {
        "username": "someString"
    }
    "b2": {
        "username": "someString"
    }
    "b3": {
        "username": "someString"
    }
}
```

As you can see, it's missing commas in the last three because they belong to the last outer_loop.index and because of that, it's not a valid JSON. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working now, it was just a matter of changing the "if" condition to:

```
{% if not (outer_loop.last and loop.last) %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}{{ '' }}{% endfor %}
```